# yii2-tinymce : Facing issue during image upload on server

Tags: image, tinymce, yii2, image-uploading

It is working on localhost.

but when uploaded on server and click of upload icon it showing the upload dialog with error: -

NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/admin/assets/5802b69e/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php?blank"

Once click on browse icon it also showing error: 
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/admin/assets/5802b69e/plugins/jbimages/ci/index.php?upload/english"

[image]

.htaccess file on root

```
 Options +Indexes
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On


 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin) 
 RewriteRule ^admin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^admin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]


 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/web/(assets|css)/ 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)  
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]


 RewriteRule ^$ frontend/web/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1


 </IfModule>
```

jbimage plugin setting code: vendor/tinymce/tinymce/plugins/jbimages/config.php

```
 $config['img_path'] = '/img'; 
 $config['upload_path'] = '/home/example/public_html/frontend/web' .  $config['img_path'];
```

Comment: using yii2 advanced and host on one domain for which added .htaccess code

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I did not solve this but i have used filemanager - pendalf89\filemanager\widgets\TinyMce

Comment: This is the exact issue I am facing up to now., http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/71542-issue-saving-text-from-form-to-txt-file/page__p__301395__fromsearch__1#entry301395. Let me try the pendalf library and see how it goes